# Adding dummy variable clears error

Tags: delphi, dll

I below is a minimum code snippet that calls a dll and returns a value. It works fine.

The dll (rtlsdr.dll) is from the Software Defined Radio field and controls a small USB dongle.

The code works fine but only if I have the dummy variable 'var junk:Integer' in the function getCenterFrequency. If I remove it or comment it I get a memory fault:

> Access violation at address 0012FEAE. Read of address 00000000

If I access the dongle directly, rather than through a call to the function, it works without flaw.

I get the same result if I run the EXE from the Delphi UI or directly.

I have installed EurekaLog but it does not capture the exception.

What could cause this strange behavior? Delphi XE2 latest version, Windows 7.

```
unit uTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

const
  rtldll = 'rtlsdr.dll';

type
  TfrmTest = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    function getCenterFrequency: longword;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    _dev: Pointer;
  end;

var
  frmTest: TfrmTest;
  _dev: Pointer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function rtlsdr_open(rtlsdr_dev_t: Pointer; index: UINT32): Integer;    stdcall; external rtldll;

function rtlsdr_get_center_freq(rtlsdr_dev_t: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;   external rtldll;

function TfrmTest.getCenterFrequency: longword;
//var
//junk: Integer;
begin
  Result := rtlsdr_get_center_freq(_dev);
end;

procedure TfrmTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  CF1, CF2: longword;
begin
  _dev := 0;
  if rtlsdr_open(@_dev, 0) <> 0 then
    ShowMessage('error');

  CF1 := rtlsdr_get_center_freq(_dev);
  CF2 := getCenterFrequency;
end;

end.
```

Comment: There's a bug in your interop most likely. We cannot see the other side of the interop.

Answer (score 3):

The RTLSDR functions use the `cdecl` calling convention, not the `stdcall` calling convention.  Also, I would suggest you change the `Pointer` pointers to match the `rtlsdr_dev_t` type that the DLL is actually using.

```
type
  rtlsdr_dev_t = record
  end;
  prtlsdr_dev_t = ^rtlsdr_dev_t;

function rtlsdr_open(out dev: prtlsdr_dev_t; index: UInt32): Integer; cdecl; external rtldll;

function rtlsdr_close(dev: prtlsdr_dev_t): Integer; cdecl; external rtldll;

function rtlsdr_get_center_freq(dev: prtlsdr_dev_t): UInt32; cdecl; external rtldll;
```

Then you can do this:

```
var
  _dev: prtlsdr_dev_t = nil;

function TfrmTest.getCenterFrequency: Uint32;
begin
  Result := rtlsdr_get_center_freq(_dev);
end;

procedure TfrmTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  CF1, CF2: UInt32;
begin
  _dev := nil;
  if rtlsdr_open(_dev, 0) <> 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('error');
    Exit;
  end;
  CF1 := rtlsdr_get_center_freq(_dev);
  CF2 := getCenterFrequency;
  rtlsdr_close(_dev);
  _dev := nil;
end;
```

Comment: I'm looking at the C# code that I am porting from and yes your right. This dll exports Cdecl.

           [DllImport(LibRtlSdr, EntryPoint = "rtlsdr_set_center_freq",   CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

        public static extern int rtlsdr_set_center_freq(IntPtr dev, uint freq);

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell, this library exports `cdecl` functions. You've imported as `stdcall`. That alone would be enough to cause the behaviour you report.